# Is there a keyboard short-cut to quickly open a URL from the Finder?

Tags: keyboard, safari

On my Windows machine I use [Win]+R to bring up a RUN prompt where I can type in a URL to quickly go to the web.

I've been searching to find a Mac equivalent (without installing any special software) and haven't had any luck.  Is there a Mac equivalent?

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com):

[image]

Comment: Yes.  That would entail extra software though, but I suppose that it is inevitable.

Comment: It turns out that Alfred is "free" software, so I broke down and installed it and I'm able to access web sites now directly from the keyboard.  Thanks to all who replied!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Yosemite, Spotlight can do this. Cmd-Space, type in your address, hit enter. I can't confirm if this works in older versions of OS X though.

Comment: I'm running Yosemite.  The Cmd-Space approach works, but only if you prefix the URL with "http://".  It's a little bit of extra typing, but I suppose it will do the trick.

Comment: Sierra doesn't need the http

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this in any version of OS X from 10.4 onward would be to create an Automator action. If you create a **service** like this one:

[image]

and save it, you can then assign a keystroke to it, so you can trigger it from the keyboard in any application.

Comment: This is a cool approach.  I hadn't considered this. Thanks.